# Access byte code generated by ruby for sample program

Tags: ruby, bytecode

Is there any way to access the byte code created by the Ruby program for the following sample piece of code?

```
x=1
x.to_s
puts x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will display the YARV instructions

```
code = <<END
x=1
x.to_s
puts x
END
puts RubyVM::InstructionSequence.compile(code).disasm
```

If you want to learn more about that you can look for the book **Ruby under a Microscope**

This would be the output

```
1.9.3-p547 :012 > code = <<END
1.9.3-p547 :013"> x=1
1.9.3-p547 :014"> x.to_s
1.9.3-p547 :015"> puts x
1.9.3-p547 :016"> END
 => "x=1\nx.to_s\nputs x\n" 
1.9.3-p547 :017 > puts RubyVM::InstructionSequence.compile(code).disasm
== disasm: <RubyVM::InstructionSequence:<compiled>@<compiled>>==========
local table (size: 2, argc: 0 [opts: 0, rest: -1, post: 0, block: -1] s1)
[ 2] x          
0000 trace            1                                               (   1)
0002 putobject        1
0004 setlocal         x
0006 trace            1                                               (   2)
0008 getlocal         x
0010 send             :to_s, 0, nil, 0, <ic:0>
0016 pop              
0017 trace            1                                               (   3)
0019 putself          
0020 getlocal         x
0022 send             :puts, 1, nil, 8, <ic:1>
0028 leave
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Rubinius you can run it like this and get the bytecode:

```
$ rbx compile simple.rb -o simple.bytecode
```

You can see a comprehensive explanation [here](http://patshaughnessy.net/2012/2/15/is-ruby-interpreted-or-compiled) and an explanation about the Rubinius compilation [here](http://rubini.us/2011/03/17/running-ruby-with-no-ruby/).

Comment: Im using MRI and i want to will MRI convert my sample code to byte or directly interpret it

Comment: I don't think that MRI is compiling to bytecode. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717490/is-ruby-really-an-interpreted-language-if-all-of-its-implementations-are-compile